# 3-d animation in C++

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

I am doing a scientific project in C++ and I need to draw simple animated 3-d images of moving atomic groups. What is a good and convenient graphics library to do that? Some general remarks are also appreciated. I work in Linux.

Thank you in advance, Roman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL of course,

one library you could use is glut for that.

have a look on http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Comment: I have worked a little in OpenGL before, and it seems to me that's an overkill. Is it object-oriented? It'd be really good, if it was.

Comment: For very small demo's OOP shouldn't be needed. if if was a lot more complex some libraries will abstract that for you.

Comment: Which libraries would you recommend?

Comment: it's too low level, so anything non-trivial would take enormous efforts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show 3D in linux, you should use OpenGL. But since it is a C library, you can use a wrapper, like for example [glt](http://www.nigels.com/glt/) or [sfml](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest library to use is [Vtk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTK). A more difficult and slower, but potentially better rasterization can be achieved using [POVRAY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Povray).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at game oriented graphics engines. They provide OO wrappers around openGL and have lots of utility functions for loading 3d model formats etc.

If you don't want to get bogged down in writing the graphics, a game oriented renderer is likely the fastest way for you to get stuff on screen.

[Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/) may be a good choice - it has a fairly large and helpful community.

Irrlicht is another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities, some perhaps more suitable than others, obviously!

I think any one of the options mentioned above would serve to do so.

I personally recommend OSG.

http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg